# Where is the list of values stored for the dropdown in this cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've been asked to change an old Excel spreadsheet I made, but I can't for the life of me find where the list of values for this dropdown are stored:

[image: a]

I've tried `Right-click > Pick from dropdown list` but the list is empty.

I've copied the cell to a new Excel sheet and uploaded it to [Dropbox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76322571/Dropdown.xlsx).

How can I edit the values?

If I can copy just the single cell to a new Excel file, the values have to be stored within the cell somewhere, not in a hidden sheet etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is done with Data Validation.

Select the cell. Go to the Ribbon. `Data -> Data Validation -> Data Validation...`. You'll see the list of values typed in manually.